# Flutter Changing Content Warning

Tags: flutter

I'm creating my first flutter app and whenever I type in a TextFormField I get spammed this error on every keypress:

```
W/TextInputPlugin( 6551): Changing the content within the the composing region may cause the input method to behave strangely, and is therefore discouraged. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78827 for more details
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6551): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6551): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6551): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6551): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6551): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6551): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6551): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6551): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

I've looked at the linked github issue and while I understand generally what the problem is, I do not see why it applies to me. Here is the code I am using to create the TextFormFields:

```
class AddressInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddressInputState createState() => _AddressInputState();
}

class _AddressInputState extends State<AddressInput> {
  TextFormField addressLine(String? hint, String? label, bool isRequired) {
    return TextFormField (
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: hint,
        labelText: label,
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        if ((value == null || value.isEmpty) && isRequired) {
          return 'Required';
        }

        return null;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: [
        Container(child: addressLine("Address Line 1", "Line 1", true)),
        Container(child: addressLine("Address Line 2", "Line 2", false)),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my main class:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'New Quote',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('New Quote'),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32), children: [
            AddressInput()
          ])),
    );
  }
```

Please let me know what I can do to write this correctly so I don't get the errors.

Comment: i'm running on web, it is working fine, do flutter clean and restart, it may solve the issue.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mention, but I'm only seeing the issue on the android emulator

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any news on that?